# `Number.MIN_VALUE` and `toString`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

(Working on a Mac), the following code:

```
Number.MIN_VALUE.toString(32);
(5e-324).toString(32);
```

both give the following expectedly long value in Safari (10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34)):

> "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"

while in Chrome (57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)), they both give "0". Similar results occur for other `toString` calls including without parameters.

Shouldn't Chrome be able to handle at least this value itself (albeit not any lower)? Is one or the other called for by the spec?

Comment: This is happening on Node 8.9.3 but not on 7.7.4...